# Accessing Properties of Subclass Object iOS

Tags: ios, properties, uiscrollview, storyboard

I've subclassed a UIScrollView (BulkProcessScroll) and in Storyboard I have a UIViewController with a scrollview in it and assigned the subclass to that scrollview.

BulkProcessScroll has one property, an int. But I can't seem to access it in code. In my UIViewController m file I can see the subclass and it's properties in the console:

[image]

But when I try to set myProcessType, the editor doesn't see it, I get an error because the editor still thinks its a UIScrollView:

[image]

Any idea of what I am doing wrong and how I can access this property?

[image]

Comment: How is `svData` declared?

Comment: I'm just assigning it in the Storyboard, thought that would handle the declaration. (See added image)

Comment: Please show the code where the `svData` property is declared

Comment: self.svData = [[GMT_BulkScrollView alloc] init]; in the UIViewController viewDidLoad

Comment: No, that is where you are assigning it, something you do not need to do if you are using a storyboard.  Show the line that declares the svData `@property`; what is its declared type?